# I don't understand why a part of my code isn't connecting to the rest

Tags: c

I have an assignment for a coding class where I have to create a code for the rock, paper scissors game, with different functions, calling rock 1 and paper 2 and scissors 3.

I also have to create a menu, then have the person chose, save that, then have the computer generate a random number and then print what they played, what the computer played and who won.

However, the last part isn't connecting, and I don't understand where I went wrong, so I'm really really lost and I would really appreciate any help.

For reference here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

float response, choice;

int playerInput() {
    printf(" For rock press 1\n ");

    printf("For paper press 2\n ");

    printf("For scissors press 3\n ");

    printf("What would you like to play? ");

    scanf("%f", &response);

    return response;
}

int computerChoice() {
    int lower = 1, upper = 3, count = 1;

    srand(time(0));

    printf("The random number that: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int choice = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
        printf("the computer chose is %d ", choice);
    }
    return choice;
}

void displayWinner() {
    if (response == choice) {
        printf("You tied, lets play again");
    }
    if (choice == 1 && response == 2) {
        printf("you won");
    }
    if (choice == 1 && response == 3) {
        printf("computer won");
    }
    if (choice == 2 && response == 1) {
        printf("computer won");
    }
    if (choice == 2 && response == 3) {
        printf("you won");
    }
    if (choice == 3 && response == 1) {
        printf("you won");
    }
    if (choice == 3 && response == 2) {
        printf("computer won");
    }
}
int main(void) {
    int pinput, cinput, dinput;
    pinput = playerInput();
    cinput = computerChoice();
    displayWinner();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you never set  `choice` with the read input.

Comment: "_isn't connecting_" suggests that you've done some bug-hunting. Good! Please share your findings.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to write this code _without_ global variables. It will make debugging this and future code much easier.

Comment: Also you're mixing types, which isn't good (at least not in this case). You declared `response` and `choice` globally as `float` but you are treating them as `int` in your main code and functions. Note, each function can have its own local variables.

Comment: Converting `float` to `int` may have some unexpected consequences; offhand, I don't think it does in your case, maybe fast-math, but I would simplify that.

Comment: `computerChoice` has an inner shadow `int choice`; the `float choice`, which is `0.0f` because you never set it, is what you return, converted to an `int`, so `cinput` is 0, which is never used. You then call `displayWinner`, since `choice = 0.0f`, the `int` value converted to float are `{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f}` you don't print anything. `float` -> `enum`. Try entering 0.

Answer (score 2):

`int choice =`

But why declare a local with the same name as a global. I suggest that's your first mistake.

On fixing it you'll find the next line prints garbage because it's now printing a %d from a `float` (that got widened to a `double`).

Comment: The global `choice` is what `displayWinner` relies on, but it is never modified by the previous function calls. Again, global variables are totally unnecessary for this, and are only making debugging more difficult.

Comment: @Chris: Plausible; but I found that globals are easier to understand for a novice than locals. Nevertheless, it's hard to know with certainty what the actual mistake is from incoherent code.